# Passing a function object to __init__ placed the default value instead of the explicit parameter into the class member

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following problem (stripped-down code):

```
class T(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def default():
    return 0

def foo():
    return 2

class A(T):
    def infl_(): pass

    def __init__(self, infl = default):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.infl_ = infl

a = A(infl = foo)
```

Now I would expect that when I call `a.infl_()` that foo gets called. However, somehow `default()` is called, and I have no idea why this is happeneing. Do I do something wrong here or should I look for a mistake somewhere else in my code?

Edit: Edited the mistakes from the comments.

Comment: This code doesn't run, please fix it. (`T` and the missing `self` in `__init__`)

Comment: When I remove the T stuff (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), add `self` to `__init__` (ditto), and run on 3.6, `a.infl_()` is 2, as expected.

Comment: Same on python 2.7.12, outputs 2 as expected.

Comment: Added the T, but where do I have to put `self` to `__init__`?

Comment: Even with the `T` and `self` in the appropriate places, I still get `2`.

Comment: Okay, probably this is already the mistake - the missing self.